# How to get CRM Processes using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, process, dynamics-crm, crm

For a task in our team, we manually deactivate CRM Processes by navigating to `Settings -> Processes`. We would like to use PowerShell scripts to get the list of active processes and deactivate them. We've been trying a few things with `Get-CrmAdvancedSetting` & `Get-CrmSetting`, but haven't really found the way. Are these the right commands or there are more?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with out of the box, the [current CRM powershell scripts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833081(v=crm.7).aspx) don't provide full tooling for all features of CRM.

Answer (score 0):

Using power-shell you can disable the CRM server which will stop the CRM services. Then when needed call the enable CRM sever power-shell command.

[Disable command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833058.aspx)

Parameter Set: Default
Disable-CrmServer [-Name]  [-Credential  ] [-Diag] [-DwsServerUrl  ] [-Timeout  ] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [ ]